# How Can I predict the frequency of buying of a product

Tags: regression, predictive-models, frequency

I'm trying to predict the frequency of buying a product based on their previous purchasing history. The approach I took as of now is,

1. Create a vector by finding the duration distance of each purchase (Xnt - X(n-1)t
2. Sort the resulted Duration distance
3. Remove Top 10% and bottom 10% results. Say X is 10% count then X = Number of elements / 10
4. Find the mean and standard deviation of remaining vector
5. Approximate duration: D = Mean + or - standard Deviation
6. Next purchase is: Last purchase date + Approximate Duration

Is there any other way to model the prediction of buying? How can I enhance or remodel?

Comment: Hmm, did you also post this one http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/95854/1390 Looks odd to have very, very similar questions on same topic. If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Surprise. Thanks for pointing me to the link. No it is not a Homework question.

Comment: Would a survival model work here? Rather than model the time to death or failure, you are looking for a model for the time to purchase. This isn't getting directly at "frequency", but at how long before next purchase. You will need some information that you can use to predict this, not just the time series of when they bought products.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. Cox Regression model looks promising. I've not done much of survival model. Some more information, yeh Cost may play a major role. Do you think any other variables?

Comment: I don't know; if you were modelling something environmental I might have some insight but as an ecologist I steer clear of thing economic :-)